# How to blur a part of an image using gaussian blur filter in deep learning with python?

Tags: blur, gaussian

I want to blur an image with gaussian filter. It should show like this:

This is the original image

[image: Original Image]

I want Two Blurred Images with different portions from the original image as shown below

[image: Left portion blurred]
[image: right portion blurred]

Please help with python code how to do this? Is there a need of segmentation first? If yes then how to do it?

I will be very thankful to you.
Waiting for the reply

Comment: yes, i have gone through this page, but that was created using a circular masking, which is not applicable to my case. As i have to create dataset for thousands of images.; where some pictures will have left portion blurred, some will have right portion blurred, some will have upper part of the image blurred and some will have lower part of the image blurred and mix match can also be there,

Comment: (in continuation to above comment....  )  ------>      but that too not in the form of rectangular portion. If you will see above blurred image, you will see that image was blurred around the boundary of children.  I can provide more examples of pictures like this if you want for more clarification.